# CDN: Origin server URL, WordPress Core files installed in sub-directory

Tags: cdn, directory

I've just purchased a plan with MaxCDN to deliver my content through CDN, but i've got a small issue before i create a pull-zone. I moved my WordPress core files out of my root and into a sub-directory. These are my current settings:

WordPress address URL: `http://example.com/wordpress`

Site address URL: `http://example.com`

The question is whether i should have my Origin Server URL and custom CDN domain name according to my WordPress address or site address. Here is the [tutorial](http://zemalf.com/1494/maxcdn-for-wordpress/) I'm currently following, in case you need to view the MaxCDN dashboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the site address URL, `http://example.com`

From the literature: `When the custom CDN URL works, you can access all files in your site via that URL and it will be delivered through the MaxCDN content delivery network.

For example, if you normally open an image from example.com/images/example.jpg, that same image now opens with cdn.example.com/images/example.jpg as well, and it's loaded from content delivery network.`

This would be exactly the same for `cdn.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads` and `cdn.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyten` or whatever else.

So going this route, everything below your root will be available via CDN, including all your wordpress files. Why complicate things?

Comment: care to explain?

Comment: @vice: I care to.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm not trying to make all files in my root available. Ill just see what i can do through trial and error, I've already talked to customer support over at MaxCDN, they suggested the same thing you did.. and recommended I do some test runs and see if everything's working as it should be. I'll try both and report it back here. thanks again.

Comment: @vice: You of course wouldn't have to use any of the cdn files for your root. Good luck.